# C socket command to open a file and send output to client

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

So i have a client.c file on a computer in my lan and a server.c file on another computer.  Essentially i start the server.c file and specify what port it needs to listen to as it waits.  I think run my client.c command by specifying the address were server.c is running and what port to send my command on.  the only thing my client sends is a filename (call it test.txt).  My server is then to take that command using recv() from the C socket protocols, and i would like to be able to read that file and send that output back to my client so that it outputs to my clients terminal.  I have figured out how to send the file as that is easy but i am having a hard time understanding how I can do this task with sockets.  Do i just need to issue a write command using send() ? Do i need to read the file and send line by line to the socket ? if thats the case and say i have 10 clients do i need to use a semaphore or mutex to make sure that the output is sent fully before moving on to the next client request?

The code does more than just what I am asking for it also has a logging feature. and i have been using
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/ as a guide. But its just sending back the contents of the file that is on the server.c machine to the client.c output that is kinda causing me to go in circles.

so in theory it should look something like this on the client side

```
./client 129.65.128.82:4443 bigfile
...entire contents of bigfile should appear here...
```

Here is my Server.c Code and Client.c (at the bottom for reference)

Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define PORT "4443" // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10 // how many pending connections queue will hold

size_t getFilesize(const char* filename) {
    struct stat st;
    if(stat(filename, &st) != 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return st.st_size;   
}


void fileOutput(char *filename){
    FILE *fptr;
    char c;
    //int check = checkFilename(filename);

    fptr = fopen(filename,"r");
    printf("We opened the file\n");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot open file \n");
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("HereWe ARE\n");
        // Read contents from file
        c = fgetc(fptr);
        while (c != EOF)
        {           
            printf ("%c", c);
            c = fgetc(fptr);
        }
    fclose(fptr);
}

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    (void)s; // quiet unused variable warning

    // waitpid() might overwrite errno, so we save and restore it:
    int saved_errno = errno;

    while ( waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0 );

    errno = saved_errno;
}

void argumentCheck(int n){
    if (n < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: server port # example port 4443\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if ( sa->sa_family == AF_INET ) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}


void logfile(FILE *fp,char *s,char *port,char *buffer,int r){
    time_t t = time((time_t*) NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char tc[256];
    strftime(tc, 256, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tm);
    fprintf(fp,"[%s] %s:%s %s %d\n",tc,s,port,buffer,r);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    //Log file creation
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("log","a");
    ///////


    ///File Size///
    //////////////



    argumentCheck(argc);
    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sockfd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;
    char *inputPort = argv[1];


    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ( (rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, inputPort, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ( (sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1 ) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if ( setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(int)) == -1 ) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if ( bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1 ) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if ( p == NULL )  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // listen allows queue of up to BACKLOG number
    if ( listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1 ) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if ( sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1 ) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while ( 1 ) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if ( new_fd == -1 ) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }
        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
        //printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);


        if ( !fork() ) { // this is the child process
            char buf[1024];
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
            printf("this is the sizeof buf %ld\n",sizeof(buf));
            recv(new_fd,buf, sizeof(buf),0);
            int size = getFilesize(buf);
            logfile(fp,s,inputPort,buf,size);
            fileOutput(buf);
 
           if ( send(new_fd, buf, size, 0) == -1)
               perror("send");
            printf("%s\n",buf);
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
       close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Client.c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT "4443" // the port client will be connecting to

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if ( sa->sa_family == AF_INET ) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: client ipaddr:port # example 129.65.128.82:4443 [filename]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int sockfd, numbytes;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

// Used to extract ipv4 and socket seperatly
    char *ip_address = strtok(argv[1],":");
    char *ip_port = strtok(NULL,":");

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));  // make sure the struct is empty
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ( (rv = getaddrinfo(ip_address, ip_port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }


    // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ( (sockfd = socket(p->ai_family,
                          p->ai_socktype,
                          p->ai_protocol)) == -1 ) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if ( connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1 ) {
            perror("client: connect");
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if ( p == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }
    //printf("we are stopping here");
    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
        s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    //strcpy(buf, "Hello World.\n");
    //printf("this is argv2 size %ld\n",strlen(argv[2]));
    strcpy(buf,argv[2]);
    //printf("this is buf size %ld\n",strlen(buf));
    //write(1, "client send: ", strlen("client send: "));
    //write(1, buf, strlen(buf));

    send(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);


    if ( (numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1, 0)) == -1 ) {
        printf("this is numbytes %d\n",numbytes);
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("this is numbytes %d\n",numbytes);
    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    //write(1, "client recv: ", strlen("client recv: "));
    //write(1, buf, strlen(buf));

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}


enter code here
```

Comment: *Do i just need to issue a write command using send()*. That would be one of the steps. It's difficult to generalise. If you want a specific answer you should show some code and ask a specific question about the code.

Comment: well i have the code that finds the file and opens it on the server.c side.  My question is how can i output that file content to the client side ? how can i write to stdout using sockets? do i write it directly onto the socket its connected to ?

Comment: *how can i write to stdout using sockets*. That's not the right question. If you want to write to a socket you wouldn't go through `stdout`. Just read the file data into a buffer and write it to the socket fd via `send` or `write`.

Comment: I have tried reading the data into a buffer which does work but when i try to send it back to the client.c computer it doesnt output to the clients terminal.  How can I do this I am using fread() to read the file from the server into a buffer and then im using send(socket,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);

Comment: on the client side i have  i am receiving recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf)-1,0) and then i try to print that buf but nothing comes out ?

Comment: It's difficult to say with snippets of code and info like that. Post a new question and include a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But for starters `strlen(buffer)` is maybe wrong if you have not ensure that the buffer is NUL terminated and is definetely wrong if the file is binary because string functions don't work with binary data.